# How to create HTML radio buttons above the Raphael canvas layer in my case?

Tags: raphael, javascript, javascript-framework

I have created a **Raphael** paper:

```
var paper = Raphael("my-canvas", '100%', '100%');
```

I would like to create some **HTML radio buttons** which are **above** the **paper canvas layer**, which means anything drawing on the paper will not cover(hide) the HTML radio buttons but behind the radio buttons.

What I have tried are illustrated below:

My **HTML** page:

```
...
<div id="layers">
  <div id="my-canvas">
  <div id="my-radio-btn">
     <input type="radio" value="apple" name="firstRadio"> Apple
     <input type="radio" value="orange" name="secondRadio"> Orange
  </div>
</div>
...
```

The **CSS** for the above page:

```
#layers {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-color: #72f342;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}
#my-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}
```

With the above code, the radio buttons are there, but if there is a Raphael object drawing on the same position of the radio buttons, the buttons are hided by the Raphael object, but what I want is to have the Raphael object **behind** the radio button, that's the HTML radio button layer is **on top of** the Raphael canvas layer.

How to get this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `z-index` property of each div (my-canvas, my-radio-btn)? I mean something like this:

```
#my-canvas {
   z-index: 1;/*what you want but less than my-radio-btn*/
}
#my-radio-btn {
   z-index: 1000;/*greater than my-canvas*/
}
```

This works for me, I have a map app with some divs floating over the raphael object. You should also be careful with the positioning of your divs. I'm using absolute positioning.